# Insert, select & ON Duplicate KEY

Tags: mysql

i'am always getting syntax error when execute this query. Any Ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO cookies (cookie, buy, orders, ordervalue) SELECT o.uid cookie,  'eby' as a, COUNT(o.price ) as b , ROUND( SUM(o.price) , 2 ) umsatz 
        FROM  `Orders` o
        WHERE uid !=  ''
        GROUP BY uid ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  buy=VALUES(a), orders=VALUES(b);
```

I'm not sure ift its possible to use alias in "on duplicate". I ve tried also to calculate the values again in the "on duplicate" part. But also  get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
  ... UPDATE buy=VALUES(a), orders=VALUES(b)
                        ^                 ^
```

`a` and `b` aren't valid in this context. Reference the name of the *column* in the column list of the INSERT to get the value that would have been inserted into that column (if the insert had succeeded)

```
  ... UPDATE buy=VALUES(buy), orders=VALUES(orders)
                        ^^^                 ^^^^^^
```

(It doesn't matter if the expressions in the SELECT have aliases or not; it's not valid to reference expressions from the `SELECT` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause.